# How to take the next line as input for discord bot

Tags: python, discord

I am making a discord bot and after the user types a certain command I want the next line of the user to be the input of a variable.

So:

```
import discord
@client.event

async def on_ready():
print('{0.user}'.format(client)+'logged in')
@client.event
async def on_message(message):

if message.author == client.user:
   return
if message.content.startswith('Lets play hangman'):
    message.channel.send('Please Guess a letter')
    userGuess = ### and here put whatever the user writes next (so no matter what is contained inside)
```

The only thing I could find is when the bot does something if the message contains something specific but in this case I just want the entire message as input no matter what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure if this is what you're looking for, but briefly looking at the [discord.py documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_message#discord.on_message) it provides an example of how to wait for a user's reply.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('$greet'):
        channel = message.channel
        await channel.send('Say hello!')

        def check(m):
            return m.content == 'hello' and m.channel == channel

        msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
        await channel.send('Hello {.author}!'.format(msg))
```

Basically, if the command started with `$greet`, then the bot would send back `Say hello!`. Then, it would wait until the user reply back.

I would recommend taking the variable `msg` value that is equal to the message the user replies back and setting that to `userGuess`.

So:

`userGuess =  await client.wait_for('message')` would be the answer.

But that's the whole message object, to get just the message itself, then just append `.content` after it.

Code for function:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.content.startswith('Lets play hangman'):
        await message.channel.send('Please Guess a letter')
        userGuess =  await client.wait_for('message')
        //prints the message content into console
        print(userGuess.content)
```

Comment: So if the user activates the code by saying a statement I want the bot to take what the user writes next as the input for a variable.

So for example:

User activates code

bot writes message and waits fro the user to respond

whatever the user writes next the bot stores

Comment: Yup, I've modified the code now, hopefully it should work now. The `print` statement prints the user's response into the console.

Comment: yes this works unfortunately I don't understand the code, or at least await and .content, since I am pretty new to coding discord bots and coding in general, what is the point of await and .content and why will it stop working after I take it away.

Comment: Check [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html) for more info @ how await/async works. 
As for `.content`, it's because the `message` the bot gets is actually the message object. What I mean by that is it contains the message contents as well as metadata about it, such as time sent, the author. But you just want the `content` property, or what the user actually typed, so `.content` is necessary for that.